# Whats and efficient way to bin pointclouds into voxels and calculate mean intensity?

Tags: velodyne, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to bin an incoming pointcloud into voxels of size x,y and calculate the mean intensity values of the pointcloud in every voxel. I'm looking for some suggestions about how to do this. I do have a gpu available so openCl is also an options.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232259/whats-and-efficient-way-to-bin-pointclouds-into-voxels-and-calculate-mean-intensity?/) by [raskolnikov_reborn](https://answers.ros.org/users/25367/raskolnikov_reborn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2016-04-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The voxel grid filter in PCL (Point Cloud Library) does almost exactly what you want: it bins point clouds into voxels and reduces the point cloud to one point per occupied voxel. I am not sure whether it also averages intensities; if not, it should be easy to add.

The PCL also has a CUDA version of the voxel grid filter.

If you don't get good answers here, try the PCL mailing list.

> Lets use this thread to discuss good ways.

Just a warning about etiquette, before you get flamed: ROS Answers isn't a forum, and this isn't a thread. The ROS Answers format isn't really well-suited for open discussions; it's meant for questions that have a clear answer. That said, I'm not sure what a good alternative is; perhaps http://discourse.ros.org/ will evolve into that.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2016-04-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raskolnikov_reborn](https://answers.ros.org/users/25367/raskolnikov_reborn/) on 2016-04-20**:
Thanks for your Input. I'll edit the question to rectify the issue. I haven't used answers.ros.org much so am a little bit unfamiliar. Won't happen again. Thanks

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-04-20**:
That's OK. You asked a good question and got a good answer. Thanks for contributing.